# TypeError: Invalid locator

Tags: javascript, protractor, reusability

Getting error TypeError: Invalid locator

I have made reusable function to check if element is displayed by passing locator in parameter. please take a look at code.

```
export function checkDisplay(Locator) {
    expect(element(Locator).isDisplayed()).to.be.true;
}

var abc= by.css('mycss');

checkDisplay(abc)
```

I am passing abc locator in this fuction, but still it is throwing this error.

below is the error.

```
at Object.check [as checkedLocator] 
at thenableWebDriverProxy.findElements
at ptor.waitForAngular.then 
at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

```
export function checkDisplay(Locator) {
    expect(element(Locator).isDisplayed()).to.be.true;
}

var abc= "by.css('mycss')";

checkDisplay(abc);
```

hope it helps you

Comment: This did not work. any other thought. what am i missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

You can Use the following code snippet.

```
 export function checkDisplay(webElement) {
        expect(webElement.isDisplayed()).to.be.true;
    }

    var abc= element(by.css('mycss'));
    checkDisplay(abc)

      or

     checkDisplay(element(by.css('mycss')))
```

Comment: I cant use this , as in my project we are following POM. so we have to fetch this element from another file. that is why i want to define reusable function.

Comment: I don't understand that if you can use 'by'  and locator name then how using element would disturb the POM. Although i don't understand complete context of using this function but here is better way to create common function for checking element is present, enabled, displayed etc.  Refer the answers section

Answer (score 0):

maybe try:

```
export function checkDisplay(loc: ElementFinder): void {
  expect(loc.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
}

let abc = $('mycss');
checkDisplay(abc);
```

Or

```
export function checkDisplay(loc: string): void {
      expect(element(by.css(loc)).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
}

let abc = 'mycss';
checkDisplay(abc);
```

Answer (score 0):

For writing common function, You can use the javaScript mixin. It allow us create object of useful or common functions and merge it to prototype of any class.
  Protractor uses element for locating webElement which returns object of ElementFinder. 
You can create mixin for ElementFinder class. I just give you a sample and then you can explore it more.

```
ElementFinderMixin = {

           function1() {},
           function2() {},

           function checkDisplay() {
    expect(this.isDisplayed()).to.be.true;}
}

Object.assign(Object.getPrototypeOf(element('')), ElementFinderMixin);
```

So preceding code will make all three functions part of ElementFinder class.
It means you can access CheckDisplay() function anywhere in your code.

Ex.

```
button = element(by.css('locator'));
button.checkDisplay();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import { protractor, browser } from 'protractor';

export function checkDisplay(Locator) {
  var abc = element(Locator);

  // Check whether element is identified or not??    
  var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
  browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(abc), 30000, "abc element Could not found");

  expect(abc.isDisplayed()).to.be.true;
}

var abc = by.css('mycss');
checkDisplay(abc);
```

Comment: wait is not helping here

Comment: What error you are getting here. could you please tell?? Use asyn and await if it related promises.